# Globbing expression in cmake: can I use brackets?

Tags: cmake, glob

In theory cmake should support globbing expression, a little bit like a glob command.

However, I cannot find a way to match, for example, "a sequence of 3 numbers, or nothing". I would guess it should be something like:

```
file (GLOB outputVar *theImportantStringIWantedToMatch{[0-9][0-9][0-9],}.dll)
```

But it does not seem to work. For example:

```
*opencv_*flann{[0-9][0-9][0-9],}.a
```

does not match a file called

```
libopencv_flann.a
```

(Should also match libopencv_flann462.a for example)

It does not even match even if I put an expression like this:

```
*opencv_*flann{.,.}a
```

Escaping the brackets or the comma does not help. Is there any way to get brackets working, or any alternative to the expression I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

So, for the moment the only solution I can come out with is repeating the expression in the 2 versions, namely:

```
file (GLOB outputVar *theImportantStringIWantedToMatch[0-9][0-9][0-9].dll
                     *theImportantStringIWantedToMatch.dll
     )
```

Comment: this looks like it for the file command. I'm not sure why there is no REGEX command for file, it seems like an obvious addition. If you can make use of one of the commands that accepts REGEX, then you could write a single expression to match them. Globs only accept * and [], so you can't do what you were hoping to do in your question.